# SqlConnection.open() throws TransactionException 0xe0434f4d

Tags: sqlconnection

Code works fine when connecting to a sql server 2005 dbase.  but when connecting to a sql server 2008 dbase it fails.

scenario:
Webservice first connects to 2008 dbase fine.  Then during a call in a COM+ object, the connect fails.

Recently upgraded projects to use VS2008 and upgraded to Sql Server 2008.

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionTimeOut))
{     
   using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(DataConnection))
   {
      try
      {
 String command = "my_StoredProcedure";

 using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command, sqlConnection))
 {
             sqlConnection.Open();  //- exception is throw right after this call in the COM+ object.
```

Any Ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing handling a SQLException

http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/04/27/584927.aspx

Comment: I have a catch for SQLException, but this type of exception is not thrown.  It is of type TransactionException.

Comment: specifically, it is a System.Transactions.TransactionException.

Drilling down in it ends with _COMPlusExceptionCode = 0xE0434F4D

Comment: Created UnhandledExceptionModule and added to web.config.

Ran my code, and same results, with no entry in the Application event log.  Same System.Transactions.TransactionException thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, binaries deployed to many PC's in network were executed fine except of few machines. All exceptions in code were handled but despite of that, `0xe0434f4d` was thrown right after start. The app always was launched locally (not from network share), no obvious issues with permissions etc. The app had .NET 3.5 among its requirements.

I examined installed .NET version (well-known registry subtree `HKLM\SOFTWARE\NET Framework Setup\NDP`) and found that subkey `v3.5\SP` (ServicePack) is NOT at `1`. It means that .NET 3.5 is installed, but **not the latest** released version (SP1). After [downloading v3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150), installing and restarting the PC, the entire problem disappeared. So the key was "*not just any .NET 3.5, but latest .NET 3.5 must be present*".